# Php POST method to 2 page

Tags: php, html, post

I just sent data to a page called `diak_o.php` with post method but I need to use this data on an another page. How can I send it to two pages or send from the first page to the next?

```
<form action="diak_o.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Bejelentkezés" />
</form>
```

Comment: Use SESSION instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store it in Sessions and access it on multiple pages like this:

Page 1:

`<form action="page2.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="page1text"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>`

Page 2:

```
<?php
session_start();
$dataFromPage1 = $_SESSION['page1text'] = $_POST['page1text'];
echo $dataFromPage1;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SESSION` or just but i think `$_POST` should still work in the next file too...

Answer (score 0):

when you send that data from this page to second page like diak_o.php in this page you can access it by below code.

in diak_o.php write code like below.

```
    <?PHP
session_start();
    echo $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION["name"] = $_POST['name'];
    ?>
```

in the other page you can use $_SESSION["name"] by accessing it.

you can also use COOKIE OF PHP.

Comment: if you have any problem you can ask me freely

Answer (score 0):

On this URL there are different methods for passing data from one page to another.

http://www.discussdesk.com/how-to-get-data-from-one-page-to-another-page-in-php.htm

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You need to give your button a name attribute, then on **diak_o.php** you check if the button isset, after that you check if the text input is not empty, else assign a session to the text input

**Your Form**

```
<form action="diak_o.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Bejelentkezés" name="submit" />
</form>
```

**diak_o.php**

```
<?php
session_start();


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(empty($_POST['name'])){

        die("enter name");
    }else{


        $_SESSION['name']= $_POST['name'];
    }




}



?>
```

**anotherpage.php**

```
<?php

    session_start();


    echo $_SESSION['name']; // will output the value from form.





?>
```

when ever your wanna use the value on your pages, just use $_SESSION['name'];

Comment: downvote for what? some SO users are have issues , if you argue with them on something they did wrong on some questions they look u up and downvote you for no reason.